# Pass width and height of a <View> to a child component

Tags: react-native, view, react-props

I'm new to react.
I have the width and height of a `<View>` and I'd like to pass theses datas to a `<Child>` component which contains these two props. I have destructurate the `<View>` layout in width and height but it seems that I can't pass theses variables to the `<Child>`(undefined name).

Here's the code:

```
  <View onLayout={(event) => { let { width, height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;}} >
    <Child width={width} height={height } />
  </View>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pay attention to you code you will see that `width` and `height` are not in scope. They exist in the scope of your event handler. Hence, you are passing variables that don't exist to the child.

Also, a proper way to do it would be using state. For example, if your view is created in a class called `AppView` then

```js
class AppView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      width: null,
      height: null,
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View onLayout={(event) => {
        let { width, height } = event.nativeEvent.layout
        this.setState({width: width, height: height}
      }}>
        <Child width={this.state.width} height={this.state.height} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

This way everytime the `onLayout` event is triggered it will set the state variables `width` and `height`. This modified values will then be passed to the child element.

Comment: thanks! I'm still struggling to identify scope, but adapting your solution to my project works definitly!

Comment: Your width and height variables are defined in the event handler callback, which is a function. So, anything inside a function scope is not visible outside. You might want to review your JS basics.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution with the useState hook:

```js
export default function App()  {

  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

    return (
      <View onLayout={(event) => {
        let { width, height } = event.nativeEvent.layout
        setWidth(width); setHeight(height);
      }}>
        <Child width={width} height={height} />
      </View>
    );
}
```